# check email with CakePHP IMAP Custom Datasource

Tags: cakephp, imap

I want to use my email on my server with CakePHP IMAP Custom Datasource.

In *database.php* I have:-

```
public $myCustomEmail = array(
    'datasource' => 'ImapSource',
    'server' => 'test.com',
    'username' => 'info@test.com',
    'password' => 'email password',
    'port' => 143,
    'ssl' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'error_handler' => 'php',
    'auto_mark_as' => array(
        'Seen',
        // 'Answered',
        // 'Flagged',
        // 'Deleted',
        // 'Draft',
    ),
);
```

When I set `port` to `143`  or `ssl` to `true` I get this error:-

> Error: Unable to get imap_thread after 4 retries. 'TLS/SSL failure for radindesign.com: SSL negotiation failed'

When `ssl` is set to `false` or I change the `port` I get this error:-

> Unable to get imap_thread after 4 retries. 'Certificate failure for test.com: self signed certificate: /CN=linux10.centraldnserver.com/emailAddress=ssl@linux10.centraldnserver.com'

What's wrong with the IMAP authentication?

Comment: I guess you would have to add ["/novalidate-cert"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) to the connection string (don't use in production!). The datasource does not support that so you might add it in [ImapSource,php](https://github.com/shahariaazam/cakephp-datasource-imap/blob/master/ImapSource.php) on line 530 and send the repository a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP IMAP Custom Datasource didnt help me i use from this :

```
// Configure your imap mailboxes
$mailboxes = array(
array(
    'label'     => 'Gmail',
    'mailbox'   => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username'  => 'yourusername@gmail.com',
    'password'  => 'yourpassword'
),
array(
    'label'     => 'My Cpanel website',
    'mailbox'   => '{mail.yourdomain.com:143/notls}INBOX',
    'username'  => 'info+yourdomain.com',
    'password'  => 'yourpassword'
),
array(
    'label'     => 'Another mail account',
    'mailbox'   => '{mail.yourdomain.com:143/notls}INBOX',
    'username'  => 'info@yourdomain.com',
    'password'  => 'yourpassword'
)
```

);

```
       //check inbox
    $current_mailbox = array(
        'label' => 'My Cpanel website',
        'mailbox' => '{mail.test.com:143/notls}INBOX',
        'username' => 'info@test.com',
        'password' => '***'
    );
    // Open an IMAP stream to our mailbox
    $stream = @imap_open($current_mailbox['mailbox'], $current_mailbox['username'], $current_mailbox['password']);

    $emails = imap_search($stream, 'SINCE ' . date('d-M-Y', strtotime("-1 week")));
```

// If we've got some email IDs, sort them from new to old and show them
        rsort($emails);

```
    $i = 0;
    $overview = array();
    foreach ($emails as $email_id) {

        // Fetch the email's overview and show subject, from and date.
        $overview[$i] = imap_fetch_overview($stream, $email_id, 0);
        $i++;
    }
```

var_dump($overview);